# Unload Prompt Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, css, checkbox, prompt

I am working on my website and I am trying to make this unique way of keeping statistics on my page. I want to know is it possible to create an UnLoad prompt for my page when for example I leave my page, the prompt pops up and give's you choices such as checkboxes and textboxed, and when done it sends all the info into an text file? Any Ideas?
Thanks in advance.

---

P.S: Let me add one more piece of information, I don't want any already made add-ons, Like it's a business site and I'd like to find out for example why did a person leave a page, if you understand my meaning?

Comment: This doesn't seem very user friendly. Why not use Google Analytics? http://www.google.com/analytics/

Comment: Kris is right ! It does not seem user friendly at all !!! Why not just send the info you need when the page loads ??
Tho i will ask what kind of feedback are you trying to get back ?? Like location maybe browser and such ? or more like how did you find this website or did you find this website helpful ??

Comment: I think you'll find people closing the tab/window rather than submitting feedback to you as they're *already* trying to leave.

Comment: I prefer to know why they leave so I will know what changes to make :)